# How can I "reset" SketchUp origin after importing DXF with "Preserve Drawing Origin" option enabled?

Tags: dxf, sketchup

I can successfully import all of my 3D DXFs into a common location so that they are referenced correctly (in reference to each other). TO do this I simply check the Import DXF "Preserve Drawing Origin" option on.

However, when I do this DFX models are placed very far away from the Sketchup "default" origin. It becomes very difficult to zoom to the location of the 3D DXFs and navigate around them.  Zoom Extents zooms out all the way showing the default origin and the imported DXFs as a spec in the distance (see screen capture). To even zoom in to the imported model is nearly impossible.

**How do I "reset" the origin and correct the extent so that sketchup zooms in onto the model when "Zoom Extent" is clicked?**

[image]

Comment: I am not sure how you would do that on import, but you could select them all and use the move tool to place them to the SU origin

Comment: Thanks. I need to retain the geo-reference. I need to move the Sketchup origin to where the model is while preserving the origin of my imported DXF meshes.

Comment: What about using the axis tool?  You can reset the axis of the model.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using SketchUp's axis tool?

http://support.google.com/sketchup/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=94978&topic=2458150&ctx=topic

GeoMark

Answer (score 0):

I posted this in the SketchUp forums as well an it seems that moving the origin axes cannot be easily accomplished. It was suggested a "control point" system is used to snap objects to a common location.  More on this here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/sketchup/rVcpIC5vAXY/PudjaxqcJT0J